# C++: Within a Set or Map, can I determine that the KeyEqual predicate is equivalent to std::memcmp?

Tags: c++, templates, introspection

Simple examples:

- Arithmetic scalars: the result of KeyEqual is equivalent to comparing bit patterns, so effectively std::memcmp.
- Pointer to null-terminated string: the result of KeyEqual is not equivalent to comparing pointer address; testing equality requires applying std::strcmp.

Can KeyEqual be queried / introspected in that way within a templated class?

Comment: Nope, that's not possible.

Comment: Amusingly, your belief about arithmetic scalars isn't wholly true; floating point NaNs with the exact same bit pattern are not considered equal to each other (or even to themselves, if you test a register against itself). Not that you should ever be putting such a thing in a `Set` or `Map`. That said, `-0.0` and `0.0` are equal to each other, but have different bit patterns.

Comment: We have is_standard_layout and is_trivial for the types themselves.  But I'm curious, what do you want to do with the answer, supposing you can get it?  It seems that it's likely not possible to know much about the implementation of the predicate, so I'm wondering why you want to .

Comment: Not sure what you mean by, _"can I determine that the KeyEqual predicate is equivalent to `std::memcmp`"_.  Why would you want to do that?  If you really want to, you can force it by wrapping your scalar/pointer in a class and overloading the `operator==` member.

Comment: Do you want to "detect" the content of KeyEqual? How about making a wrapper to the algorithm?

Comment: Do you mean the `KeyEqual` type parameter of `std::unordered_`? That can be an arbitrary function object? Or do you mean the default, `std::equal_to`?

Comment: @ShadowRanger, I am well aware of IEEE 754 and the rulls for comparison of both NaNs and signed zeros.  At least in gcc's implementation, you are correct about signed zeros, but wrong about NaNs.  In point of fact std::nan("1") is treated as equal to both std::nan("1") and std::nan("2").  Try it for yourself.

Comment: @JohnYates: Hmm... I tried it for myself, and `std::nan("1")` was not equal to itself, or any other NaN: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tY2/CoMwEMb3PMWRLoo4tKNVxz5BoUuX44wSiFFMApHiqzdNbUFo6dhvuOF@3x8ax7wjCmEnNSnXCChp6EclfM22lxyMnQT2NWNSW@hR6iSFG2MQhc4O4KECY5ui0KgTvufpcWPzN1uhbCGJuQrmZxe8tTppcBbKEvh5cuKq@attAaGM@Ok9YaSb@WPE/2dkCeFOrcLOhPyCSsUrvJ0w5DFXUZYd8AE "C++ (gcc) – Try It Online") Compiler variation/defect perhaps? TIO is getting a bit out of date, but I wouldn't expect newer releases to be more wrong.

Comment: @ShadowRange, Clearly , I was not sufficiently precise in my statement.  My point was about STL containers, in particular std::set.  [Try in online](https://tio.run/##tY2/CoMwEMb3PMWRLoo4tKNVxz5BoUuX44wSiFFMApHiqzdNbUFo6dhvuOF@3x8ax7wjCmEnNSnXCChp6EclfM22lxyMnQT2NWNSW@hR6iSFG2MQhc4O4KECY5ui0KgTvufpcWPzN1uhbCGJuQrmZxe8tTppcBbKEvh5cuKq@attAaGM@Ok9YaSb@WPE/2dkCeFOrcLOhPyCSsUrvJ0w5DFXUZYd8AE).  Clearly, in the STL container world there is only one NaN and only one floating point zero.

Comment: @Wyck, I am experimenting with hash functions in the context of sets and maps.  A hash function is defined to return a uint64.  My probe table size is always a prime so hash % tableSize incorporates all entropy in that uint64.  The problem is what to do with keys that are 64 bits or less.  Any mixing hash likely looses some amount of entropy.  So, for scalars and pointers 64 bits or less, I would like to stipulate that  the hash function is identity.  That works if a pointer denotes an object's identity (KeyEqual is pointer comparison).  It fails if the pointed to object has value semantics.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, (Apologies, got your handle wrong in previous comment.)  Here is an updated [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rY/PasMwDIfvfgrhXRKCQ5tjm@U1dslFdZTW4NjFVmB/2KvPM@khoxS2bvNBmJ/1fZb0@ayOWqf0YJy280DQ6gn51Ik1MD5yIJy@ZpG4E8I4hgmNK0p4E5BP5GG3y2/t4OeDpQ7ifs21nxnaFmIdzStlJt8lHGj0gQDdCxgXKXDsndyLC1ZfomLhHbpCbmVZfuvEkSnANdvLbZ/p/9Kj83z65TfNX7ZorvXaEobip8Kl@8Z01abe3DnUgtzaVN3vUqvrPaUPPVo8xqSe0Npc6ZkDJpVlj7qqGvwE) link.

Comment: @JohnYates: Ah, you were saying that `set` and `map` treated NaNs as being equivalent. You're subtly incorrect. They treat NaNs as being equivalent to *all* `double`s, because, for all simple inequality comparisons, `cmp(NaN, x)` and `cmp(x, NaN)` are always false, so `!cmp(x, NaN) && !cmp(NaN, x)` is true, and it's considered equivalent. This violates the strict weak ordering requirements, so NaNs aren't legal members (without the use of custom comparators). The result is that if a `set` contains an NaN, it won't insert *anything* else; if it contains a non-NaN, it won't insert an NaN.

Comment: As for floating point zero, that's just another artifact of weird floating point rules. `-0.0` is distinct from `0.0`, but is considered equal to it for all comparison operators. My point was that there are cases in IEEE 754 floating point where there are distinct bit patterns, for arithmetic scalars, which would 1) Compare equal by `KeyEqual` but not by `memcmp` (`-0.0` and `0.0`), and 2) Compare not equal by `KeyEqual` but equal by `memcmp` (two NaNs with same bit pattern). All of this applies to `std::unordered_set` though, not `std::set` (which has no `KeyEqual`).

Comment: Point is, none of this is something the STL is special-casing for floating point, it's just the weirdness of how floating point works (in fact, `std::unordered_set` behaves opposite `std::set` for NaNs, because each one is considered a new unique value; you can't actually membership test for any of them though). Integers are safe; if they're the same type and the same bit pattern, then testing for `memcmp` returning 0 should be equivalent to testing `==`. The rules don't hold, in either direction, for floating point values in the presence of signed zero, NaNs, and probably other weirdo cases.

Answer (score 1):

Basically `std::memcmp` is **never** used for comparison of objects. The problem is that objects can contain *padding bits* that doesn't affect objects value, but can have random value themselves.

So, two objects with same value can have different *object representation*. Quote from here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object

For an object of type `T`:

- its *object representation* is the sequence of `sizeof(T)` objects of type `unsigned char` (or, equivalently, `std::byte`) (since C++17) beginning at the same address as the `T` object,
- its *value representation* is the set of bits that hold the value of its type `T`, and
- its *padding bits* are the bits in the object representation that are not part of the value representation.

Moreover some objects in C++ may have different "logical value" than its *value representation* in which case they overload comparison operators.

This is even mentioned in description of `std:memcmp`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcmp

> This function reads *object representations*, not the *object values*, and is typically meaningful for only trivially-copyable objects that have no padding. For example, `memcmp()` between two objects of type `std::string` or `std::vector` will not compare their contents, and `memcmp()` between two objects of type `struct{char c; int n;}` will compare the padding bytes whose values may differ when the values of `c` and `n` are the same.

Answer (score 0):

In general, no. What you are asking for might not be available to the compiler, or is otherwise equivalent to the halting problem.

The compiler might have only this, with the implementation in another translation unit.

```
struct KeyEqual {
    bool operator()(int lhs, int rhs);
};
```

You can test that it is `std::equal_to<Key>`, and that `Key` is either a scalar, or an array of scalar. That will miss classes whose data members are all scalars, but given `struct Padded {char c; int n;}`, `std::equal_to<Padded>` is not equivalent to `std::memcmp`.

But you shouldn't care. Just use `KeyEqual` directly.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already noted, `std::memcmp` can't be replaced for any complex objects; if they're not trivially copyable, or contain padding bits, then `std::memcpy` would disagree with any sane logical equality comparison.

But it's worse than that: Even in the most basic cases you described, `KeyEqual` is not equivalent to `std::memcmp`, thanks to the weirdness of IEEE 754 binary floating point, where some floating point values with different bit patterns are still equal to each other (`-0.0 == 0.0` is true, but `memcmp` would see them as not equal; if you were on a truly insane system, canonical and non-canonical representations of many numbers representing the same value could also do this), and other floating point values compare not equal to *any* other floating point value, even one with the exact same bit pattern (`std::nan("1") == std::nan("1")` is false, but `memcmp` would see them as equal).

Thanks to floating point weirdness, with a `std::unordered_set<double>`:

1. You can insert the *same* NaN value (e.g. `std::nan("1")`) repeatedly (continually increasing the size of the `unordered_set`, even though all the values have the same bit pattern); this is perhaps not all that interesting (you could never membership test for, or remove, any of them without iterating the whole thing and manually testing with `std::isnan` to *bypass* the native lookup behavior of `std::unordered_set`), but we're already in a place where the behavior of using `std::memcmp` would differ.
2. If you insert both `-0.0` and `0.0`, regular `std::equal_to` will treat them as equivalent (keeping whichever was inserted first, so insertion order matters), but `std::memcmp` would see them as different (because the bit patterns differ).

While item #1 is probably not an issue†, #2 is relevant; anything that uses plain `==` testing would see `-0.0` and `0.0` as being the same, but if you decide to swap in `std::memcmp` when using plain `==`, you'd change the behavior and treat them as distinct, so both could coexist in the same `unordered_set`.

So even in your most basic examples (arithmetic scalars), it's already wrong to say that a `KeyEqual` predicate that boils down to an `x == y` comparison can be safely replaced with a `std::memcmp(&x, &y) == 0` comparison. Basically the only case where your assertion is valid is plain integers (which *can* have trap representations that do all sorts of weird things, on most systems they either don't have traps, or only have a single trap bit pattern; even when they have traps, actually using them with a trap representation is undefined behavior, so you're not responsible for handling them).

It's not like you'd gain anything from using `std::memcmp` there anyway; barring compilers undoing your nonsense, it would force any values in registers to get dumped to memory just to use a less efficient means of comparison. Straight up comparisons of two registers (or a register and a memory value) would be far more efficient.

---

† Neither `std::set`/`std::map` nor `std::unordered_set`/`std::unordered_map` do anything resembling a sane thing with NaNs and default comparators/equality testers, and in fact, using NaNs with the sorted collections and any of the standard comparators is violating the strict weak ordering requirement, so without a custom comparator, you're off in Undefined Behavior Land (or the adjacent Unspecified Behavior Land and similar forbidden realms). Beyond that, the rest of `set`/`map`'s spec, combined with NaN comparison rules basically requires that NaNs be treated as *equal* to everything (because `x CMP NaN` and `NaN CMP x` must both be false for any comparison, and equivalence is defined by the comparison returning false with the arguments in either order, which it always will if an NaN is involved), while `unordered_set`/`unordered_map` will behave "normally" for NaNs and treat them as being *not* equal to anything, not even other NaNs with the same bit pattern, so switching from sorted to hash-based collections would completely change behavior.